# Selecting a value in dropdownlist in asp.net, vb.net is code behind

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdownlist populating list of values in it in page_load .

I want to select a specific value

```
Me.DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment.SelectedValue = ct.LocalOfficeName
Me.DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment has list of values.
```

Problem is: It always pointing to first item.

i tried this

```
For Each item As ListItem In Me.DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment.Items
    If item.Equals(ct.LocalOfficeName) Then
        item.Selected = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
DV.Dispose()
```

still pointing to the first item. i debugged, it should point to the last item.
ct.localoffice is containing the last item in the list. This is how i am populating the dropdown :

```
Dim DV As DataView = New DataView(CacheVariable.States.Tables(0))
Dim DRV As DataRowView
Me.DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment.Items.Clear()
DV = New DataView(CacheVariable.LocalOffice.Tables(0))
If DV.Count > 0 Then
    For Each DRV In DV
        Me.DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment.Items.Add(New ListItem(DRV("Name"), DRV("LocalOfficeID").ToString))
    Next
End If
```

Comment: If you're setting it then your code should work. Things to check: You have the `value` in your list that matches ct.LocalOfficeName - note, this is the value, not necessarily the same as the text.
you have set `DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment.DataValueField` to `LocalOfficeName` or `ct.LocalOfficeName` (depending on other factors) Can you show your `ASPX` page? and a little more of your code-behind?

Comment: Probably the most common cause of this behavior is that the code which populates the drop down list runs _after_ (sometimes a second time) the code which makes use of the selected value (either setting it or reading it).  Show more code and indicate the full order of events here.  If you can show the entire code-behind with the irrelevant parts removed that would be helpful.

Comment: Can you show us any ASPX for the drop down list? or are you creating it dynamically?

Comment: Based on your last edit... When you debug that loop, for what value does it set `item.Selected = True`?  Does it only set it once?  What is the `SelectedValue` after the end of the loop?  If it's correct after the end of the loop, when does it change?  Again, it sounds like the problem is elsewhere in the code here but we can't know without seeing the rest of the relevant code.

Comment: I don't think you have the DataValueField set, or you have it set to the wrong property; though we REALLY need to see the declaration of your list to help more

Comment: You keep adding code to the question, which is good.  But there's still one piece we're trying to get from you that remains unclear... _When_ does each of these code blocks run?  The page life cycle in web forms is both highly unintuitive and highly important in these matters.  Create a page with nothing else on it but this one issue, thus reproducing the issue with minimal code.  Show us the _entire_ code-behind for that page.

Comment: all these code is in page_load event.

Comment: Me.DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment.DataValueField = ct.LocalOfficeName.ToString()
it is holding the correct value. but it is not selecting the value in the page

Comment: @PeterJennings: Wait, where are you using `DataValueField`?  I don't see that in the code you've shared.  (Again, share _all_ relevant code.)  That might be the problem.  That doesn't set the value, that sets the field from which to determine the value when binding the control to a data source.  But you're not binding it to a data source, you're creating `Item`s manually.  So `DataValueField` shouldn't have any use for your needs.

Comment: Me.DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment.SelectedValue = ct.LocalOfficeName.ToString() - why this is not selecting the correct value. In my dropdown say 5 items are there, i want to select the value that is there in ct.localoffice. when the page open the dropdown box has to point to the correct value, not the first value.

Comment: @PeterJennings: When you debug the code, on the line you just indicated what are the `Item`s in `DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment`?  Specifically, what are their values?  What is `ct.LocalOfficeName.ToString()` when that line is evaluated?  Immediately after that line, what is the `SelectedValue` of `DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment`?  Is it correct immediately after that line executes?  If so, at what point afterward does it change?  We're really trying to help you here, but you're withholding information.

Comment: DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment has the list of items abc, def, xyz. ct.localofficename.string contains xyz. The dropdownselected value is always pointing to abc

Comment: @PeterJennings: Items have two attributes, Name and Value.  You're setting them to two different values, `DRV("Name")` and `DRV("LocalOfficeID")`.  You've indicated only one attribute, still withholding information.  Which of those two is "abc" or "xyz" in this case?  `SelectedValue` is looking at the Value, not the Name.

Comment: Me.DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment.SelectedValue it is containing "1"  not "xyz"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on lengthy comments on the question...

You're looking for the wrong value when you try to set the `SelectedValue`.  Take a look at how you create your `ListItem`s:

```
Me.DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment.Items.Add(New ListItem(DRV("Name"), DRV("LocalOfficeID").ToString))
```

When [creating a `ListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f7h2h8h.aspx), you pass it both its *display text* and its *underlying value*.  In this case, you're setting them as:

- Display Text = `DRV("Name")`
- Underlying Value = `DRV("LocalOfficeID")`

According to your comments, the sample data looks something like this:

```
LocalOfficeID | Name
--------------------
1             | abc
2             | def
3             | xyz
```

Then, when you try to manually set the `SelectedValue`, you're passing it the wrong value.  You're essentially trying to do this:

```
DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment.SelectedValue = "xyz"
```

None of the `Value` properties on the `ListItem`s are `"xyz"`.  They're `"1"`, `"2"`, and `"3"`.  In order to set the `SelectedValue`, you need this:

```
DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment.SelectedValue = "3"
```

So this line needs to change:

```
Me.DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment.SelectedValue = ct.LocalOfficeName
```

On your `ct` object you need to get the *identifier* for the object, not its *display name*.  Probably something like this (though without knowing what `ct` is I can't be certain):

```
DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment.SelectedValue = ct.ID
```

If you don't have the identifier, then you can find it on the `DropDownList` by searching for the display name.  Something like this should work, though there may be a more elegant way to do it:

```
DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment.SelectedIndex = DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment.Items.IndexOf(DropDownList_LocalOfficeAssignment.Items.FindByText(ct.LocalOfficeName))
```

Using the identifier would be *much* cleaner, though.

Comment: My scenario is like this changeoffice : dropdownlocaloffice; the dropdown initially points to the value in the object i.e ct.localoffice. once the user select the drop down, the dropdown should show all the values in the list. so i am populating all the values when pageload.   ct is an object.  Dim ct As Classtemp = SessionVariable.Classtemp

Comment: @PeterJennings: I'm not sure what you're getting at with that comment.  For one thing, I still don't know what `Classtemp` is or what fields it has.  And the rest of the comment doesn't really indicate if there's a further problem with the code.  The issue you're facing is that you're trying to use the display name of a record to identify it, when the `DropDownList` uses the identifier to identify it.  You should be using the identifier consistently throughout the code.  Is there still an issue beyond that?  Is something still not working?

Comment: I tried the last option. Now the problem is it is always pointing to the xyz. My scenario is first time only it should point to xyz. once the user click on the drop down, if he select 'def' the dropdown box must stick to 'def' not xyz. I am putting the entire code in page_load event.

Comment: @PeterJennings: Look, I really can't help if you don't share useful information.  You can update the question as many times as you'd like to add updated information.  Show the updated complete code, indicate what values are in relevant objects at runtime, step through the code in a debugger and indicate where the observed behavior deviates from the expected behavior.  All you keep repeating is some vague high-level requirement for the software.  I can't write it for you.  You have to be able to debug the code a little bit to provide useful information.

Comment: @PeterJennings: If I were to _guess_ based on your description and based on the fact that you previously indicated that this all happens in `Page_Load`, it sounds like you're setting the value in `Page_Load` on every post back.  If you're posting back to the code when the selection changes (which is bad practice in almost every case) then you're _probably_ changing the value in `Page_Load` on the post back before you read it in the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because the `DropDownList` does `DataBind()` after you set the `SelectedValue`.  Do you have the `DropDownList.DataSourceID` property set?  Are you calling `DataBind()` later in the page lifecycle?

Comment: @PeterJennings: Please place relevant code in an edit to the question.  The code in that comment is entirely unreadable.

Comment: OK I see that you are not even data binding, you are manually populating the Items collection.  Finding the problem here is still just a matter of debugging, checking if and when the Items collection gets filled, checking the value of `SelectedValue`, and watching for re-binding to occur later.